# Need to determine button clicked in a JQuery mobile popup and perform actions based thereon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I am having a problem with a JQM popup.  The popup has 3 buttons, and the action taken in the main program depends on which button is clicked.  The code in the main program is run more than once and I am not sure why.

The simple example below uses an alert to display which button on the popup was clicked. When the popup is called the first time, it works as hoped, the 2nd time, the alert is displayed twice, the 3rd time, the alert is displayed 3 times, etc.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>    

    function doCustomDialog(text1,button1,button2,button3,callback)
    {
        $("#customDialog .customDialogDesc").text(text1);

        $("#customDialog .customDialogOption1").text(button1).on("click.customDialog", function(){ 
            callback("option1");
        });

        $("#customDialog .customDialogOption2").text(button2).on("click.customDialog", function(){ 
            callback("option2");
        });

        $("#customDialog .customDialogOption3").text(button3).on("click.customDialog", function(){ 
            callback("option3");
        });

        $("#customDialog").popup("open");
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <INPUT type="button" id="confirm" value="Save data" />

        <div data-role="popup" id="customDialog" data-title="Are you sure?" class="ui-content">
            <p class ="customDialogDesc">???</p>
            <a href="#" class ="customDialogOption1" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Yes</a>
            <a href="#" class ="customDialogOption2" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">No</a>
            <a href="#" class ="customDialogOption3" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>     

<script>
$("#mainPage").on("pageshow", function(e) {
    $("#confirm").click(function() {        
        doCustomDialog("A similar record already exists.  Do you want to Update the existing record or Add a new record?", "Update", "Add", "Cancel",
        function( returned ) 
        {
            //Do things depending on the button clicked, for now just display which button was clicked 
            alert(returned);
        });
    }); 
}); 

</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have any of the answers below worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Use `popupafterclose` to unbind any attached `click` event. Also, note the direct parent of `data-role=popup` should be `data-role=page`.

```
$(document).on("popupafterclose", "#customDialog", function () {
  $('#customDialog a').off('click');
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4c9Gz/)**

**Note:** To change button's text, use `.ui-btn-inner` selector i.e. `$("#customDialog .customDialogOption1 .ui-btn-inner").text(button1)` in order not to lose button style.

**Update:** If you wish to go with the above note, you then need to unbind click `.ui-btn-inner` i.e. `$('#customDialog a .ui-btn-inner').off('click');`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are attaching another event to each button for every successive time the popup is opened. You can prevent this by using `one()` to attach the events:

```
$("#customDialog .customDialogOption1").text(button1).one("click.customDialog", function(){ 
    callback("option1");
});

$("#customDialog .customDialogOption2").text(button2).one("click.customDialog", function(){ 
    callback("option2");
});

$("#customDialog .customDialogOption3").text(button3).one("click.customDialog", function(){ 
    callback("option3");
});
```

Alternatively, you could remove all the events attached to the buttons first by adding the following line at the start of your `doCustomDialog` function:

```
$("#customDialog a").off();
```

Then you can re-attach then using `on` as you currently do.